# Equation is not numbering section and subsection

Tags: equations, numbering

I am currently writing protocolls with latex. I want to numerate my equations like this: (1.1), (2.3) and so on, but it´s only numbering from (1) to (n) without remarking the sections. My preamble is, but with it its not working how i want:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{subfiles}
%\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm,mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\definecolor{softgreen}{rgb}{.6,.98,.6}
\usepackage{parskip} %Deaktiviert Absatzeinrückung
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hyperref} %Anklicken von Referenzen ermöglichen
\usepackage[a4paper, includefoot, left=24mm, right=24mm, top=15mm, bottom=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{cleveref} %Referenzieren ermöglichen
\usepackage{chemformula}
\graphicspath{{Grafiken/}}
%\usepackage{uhrzeit}




\begin{document}


\section{Theoretische Grundlagen}

\begin{equation}
2 + 3 = 5
\end{equation}  
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Please clarify your desired output. In the title of the question you mention section and subsection, while the numbering scheme you describe in the body of the question only seems to incorporate the section number.

Comment: Adding `\counterwithin{equation}{section}` to your preamble result in the equation begin numbered with `1.1`.

Comment: Entirely unrelated but you might be interested in cleaing up/restructuring your preamble a bit. For example, you can replace `\usepackage{color} \usepackage{colortbl}` wirh `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`. Also, I would suggest using the `enumitem` package instead of `enumerate` as the former  supersedes the latter.

Comment: While it it for the most cases true that the load order of packages does not matter, there are some exceptions that you might want to keep in mind. `hyperref` should, with some exceptions like `cleveref`, be the last package in the preamble. So move `geometry` and `chemformula` before the `hyperref` package.

Comment: Lastly, you should recieve a warning such as "Usage of package `parskip` together with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended." To get a somewhat similar output without using the `parskip` package, you can use the `parskip=half` class option.